# VSCode How to expand string expression in watch "...+207 more"

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Im trying to debug a Go program but i need to view whole strings on the watch tab in debug, How can i expand the "...+207 more" when i copy value

Tried searching for any relevant issues regarding this before, using the "Go" extension for VSC

What i currently get when copying the value:

```golang
"client_id=61338943061452905&client_secret=8xc2sOsX...+207 more"
```

If anyone is able to provide insight or another way of copying the string in runtime without needing to add a `print` etc. in there